# windows stops working when upgrading to XP service pack 3

Tags: service-pack, windows-xp

i have a laptop that i upgraded to **windows XP service pack 3** (as i wanted to install some software that required SP3).  after installing it, and rebooting, my machine slowed down dramatically.  even with essentially nothing running, i couldn't bring up the task manager, the task bar at the bottom of the machine kept freezing and disappearing and overall it was essentially unusable.  I just tried uninstalled SP3 from **Add/Remove Programs** and rebooted and everything seems to work fine now.

is there any suggestions on why my windows XP laptop wont work after installing XP SP3.

in terms of the software that i have installed, its pretty bare:

1. Internet Explorer 8
2. Firefox
3. McAfee Enterprise VirusScan
4. MS Office (excel, word, etc)

any suggestions would be great because not having XP SP3 is a bottleneck in allowing me to install some new software that i would like to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall McAfee first, then install SP3, see if it runs well without McAfee, then decide what AV to install.

Comment: I would recommend Microsoft Security Essentials. I seem to have very good coverage and success with it, and it's free. (I'm not connected to MS in any way except as a user). Regards,

Comment: +1 for removing McAfee. It's a dog on any machine we've had the misfortune of looking at (I work in a tech shop). And +1 for Security Essentials.